# XPath expression - help needed

Tags: xml, xpath

I have sample XML like this:

```
<users>
    <user name="user1">
        <roles separator=",">ADM,USER</roles>
    </user>
    <user name="user2">
        <roles separator=",">ADM,GUEST</roles>
    </user>
    <user name="user3">
        <roles separator=",">READER,GUEST</roles>
    </user>
</users>
```

Is there any way to get all **users** who are in role **GUEST** using **XPath expression** ?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short and correct XPath 1.0 one-liner. :)

Comment: I have fixed an issue found by@Per-T -- now my answer provides a really good XPath 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use XSLT 2.0 I would suggest you to tokenize the string of roles. Using `contains()` is fine as long as you don't start having role names like "EXTERNALGUEST" or similar since it would match that aswell.

```
/users/user[tokenize(roles, roles/@separator) = 'GUEST']/@name
```

This XPath will tokenize the `roles` depending on the `@separator` and return the users which has this role.

Comment: Unfortunately I have an error while I'm trying to use tokenize function with c#.

Comment: Oh, I belive that you need to use XSLT 1.0 if you gonna implement this in C#. If you don't wanna use Saxon .Net. 

I don't think it's possible to solve this issue with a simple XPath expression in 1.0, but I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

However, it is possible to solve using recursive templates in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath expression will select all users whose roles node contains `GUEST`.

```
//user[contains(roles, 'GUEST')]
```

See the [contains](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_contains.html) xpath function.

Comment: I think you should say that this works if there is no other role having "GUEST" as a part, like "EXTERNALGUEST" that it was commented.

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/users/user/[roles[contains(concat(@separator, ., @separator), 
                            concat(@separator, 'GUEST', @separator)
                           )
                  ]
            ]
```

**This selects all desired `user` nodes, regardless whether `'GUEST'` is the only role or it is at the start, in the middle or at the end of the string**.

Comment: I belive you actully ment: `/users/user[roles[contains(concat(@separator, ., @separator), concat(@separator, 'GUEST', @separator))]]/@name` since your XPath is broken. But I'll give you +1 anyway because I didn't come up with the idea... ;)

Comment: @Per-T: Thanks for noticing this -- I was very tired and sleepy yesterday when replying... :(

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! I was expecting that you would come with something smart like this.